# TypeError openpyxl in Python

Tags: python, excel, typeerror, openpyxl

I want to determine workers' salary and tax due to their profession. The code is that:

```
import openpyxl as xl
wb = xl.load_workbook('Book1.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

dictionary = {
    'Boss': 1000,
    'Manager': 670,
    'Secretary': 300,
    'Accountant': 470,
    'Redactor': 590,
    'Chef': 270,
    'Servant': 170
}

for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    profession = sheet.cell(row, 2)
    salary = dictionary.get(profession.value, profession.value)
    salary_cell = sheet.cell(row, 3)
    salary_cell.value = salary
    tax = salary * 0.14
    tax_cell = sheet.cell(row, 4)
    tax_cell.value = tax
    net_salary = salary - tax
    net_salary_cell = sheet.cell(row, 5)
    net_salary_cell.value = net_salary

wb.save('Book2.xlsx')
```

But I got this error:

> tax = salary * 0.14
>   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'

Then I tried to turn salaries in dictionary into string and coded like that:

```
wb = xl.load_workbook('Book1.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

dictionary = {
    'Boss': '1000',
    'Manager': '670',
    'Secretary': '300',
    'Accountant': '470',
    'Redactor': '590',
    'Chef': '270',
    'Servant': '170'
}

for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    profession = sheet.cell(row, 2)
    salary = dictionary.get(profession.value)
    salary_cell = sheet.cell(row, 3)
    salary_cell.value = salary
    tax = int(salary) * 0.14
    tax_cell = sheet.cell(row, 4)
    tax_cell.value = tax
    net_salary = int(salary) - tax
    net_salary_cell = sheet.cell(row, 5)
    net_salary_cell.value = net_salary

wb.save('Book2.xlsx')
```

But now:

> tax = int(salary) * 0.14
>   TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Your variable “salary” doesn’t have a value...

Comment: print(profession) and print(salary) I'm pretty sure one of those is not what you think it is

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem. It was about sheet.max_row
when I print salary and profession i get a bunch of none. Then I write 9(maximum number of written rows in file) instead of sheet.max_row + 1

Answer (score 0):

Today I spent 5 hours looking for the cause of same problem. In my case, everything was in the Excel settings. After I set in the Excel settings "Use R1C1 reference style" the problem was solved!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30877501)